# Kivy - Touch not answer everytime on android

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy

I have an App which is working fine, but sometimes I don't have touch answer, no matter where (Button, Tabbed Panel...). This happens in other android I tested, different versions and different cell phones. Sometimes I touch once and answer is ok, sometimes I need touch two or three times. Is not just me, other people using same app in others cell phones had the same problem. 
I built with buildozer and have no idea why I have this behavior.
I built and install touch tracer (that demo app) and all the touchs were recognized, so I suppose the problem is not with buildozer, but just is case, this is my buildozer.spec (for my app, not for touch tracer):

```
    [app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = DAP

# (str) Package name
package.name = DAP

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = com.doatlanticoaopacifico

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ttf,db

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = sqlite3,kivy,datetime,plyer,ecdsa,paramiko

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/figura.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/logo.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,CAMERA 

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
android.private_storage = False

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

I can provide all the code and apk for test if necessary. I found similiar problems in other forums (stackoverflow too) but in all of them the touch just doesn't work - in my case doesn't work many times, but not with a pattern, apparently.

EDIT

This is a short example of a code which have the same problem:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.5')

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel

from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
import kivy.metrics as conv


class Dap(FloatLayout):
    telal,telaa  = Window.size


class DapApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Dap()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DapApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0
#:import conv kivy.metrics

<Dap>:

    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False
        background_color: (1, 1, 1, 0)
        background_normal: ''
        background_disabled_normal:''
        background_down: ''
        background_disabled_down: ''
        tab_width:root.telal/4
        tab_height:conv.cm(1.25)

        TabbedPanelItem:
            background_color: (0, 0, 1, 0.7)
            background_normal: ''
            background_disabled_normal:''
            background_down: ''
            background_disabled_down: ''
            font_size: 18
            color: (1,1,1,1)
            text: 'Login'
            Label:
                text: 'Login tab content area'
                background_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                background_normal: ''
                size:(root.telal,conv.cm(3))
                color:(0, 0, 1, 1)


        TabbedPanelItem:
            background_color: (0, 0, 1, 0.7)
            background_normal: ''
            background_disabled_normal:''
            background_down: ''
            background_disabled_down: ''
            font_size: 18
            color: (1,1,1,1)        
            text: 'Home'
            Label:
                text: 'Home tab content area'
        TabbedPanelItem:
            background_color: (0, 0, 1, 0.7)
            background_normal: ''
            background_disabled_normal:''
            background_down: ''
            background_disabled_down: ''
            font_size: 18
            color: (1,1,1,1)        
            text: 'Pass'
            Label:
                text: 'Pass tab content area'
        TabbedPanelItem:
            background_color: (0, 0, 1, 0.7)
            background_normal: ''
            background_disabled_normal:''
            background_down: ''
            background_disabled_down: ''
            font_size: 18
            color: (1,1,1,1)        
            text: 'Fotos'
            Label:
                text: 'Fotos tab content area'
```

Comment: No need to provide all your stuff, just a minimal example that can reproduce your problem. If touchtracer works then maybe there is some fighting in your code or you do too much stuff at one touch (maybe you have some `for`/`while` that freezes UI)? By cutting the code as much as possible you should isolate the problem correctly and even find a way how to fix it.

Comment: I don't believe is a for issue, cause I have the same problem in another simpler example (I insert in edition now). Maybe is something with Tabbed Panel, my app and that example use Tabbed Panel. Touch tracer, for example, doesn't use that.

Comment: And, of course, the problem is not just on buttons in Tabbed Header, but in the content too.

Comment: `def on_touch_down(self, touch): print touch` in the `FloatLayout` prints always when you click? Change it to append text somewhere if you don't want to mess with logcat.

Comment: Good Idea, I'll check, probably just after tomorrow. Give you a feedback as soon as I can, thanks! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me and some other people I know had the same problem, and we got it fixed by upgrading to kivy 1.9.2_dev.

Try changing requirements to `requirements: kivy==master, ...`

Comment: I guest it solved! For me worked, but I asked other friends to test it. If confirm I accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: did you find any problem with older android version when using kivy==master to compile? I have 6.0 and your solution solve my problem, but my friends tried with 5.0 and is not working. App crash after presplash screen. I didn't change any other thing and the app used to run before. Is this just a coincidence?

Comment: @awulll I have android 4.4. If the app crashes, that means there are some api differences between kivy master and 1.9.1 that have to be resolved. Read logcat. PS: I assume your friends have either another app than you or another version of it?

Comment: I built the app and send then to test. Is the same version. But they had an older version installed. I ask them trying again uninstalling the older version before install the new one, but the problem was the same and I cant see the logcat of them (they are just testers). I'll try to reproduce that problem and look at the logcat. If your android is older and work so I must be able to solve it.